# junit cannot catch a generic exception

Tags: java, exception, junit

The java code:

```
public static <T extends Throwable> void checkNotNull(Object value, String name, Class<T> exceptionClass) throws T, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    if (value==null)
      throw ExceptionHelper.constructException(exceptionClass, name + " should not be null");
}

static <T extends Throwable> T constructException(java.lang.Class<T> exceptionClass, String message) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    Constructor<T> constructor = exceptionClass.getConstructor(String.class);
    T result = constructor.newInstance(message);
    return result;
}
```

The junit code:

```
@Test
public void testCheckNotNull() {
    try {
    ValidationUtility.checkNotNull(null, "valuename", exceptionClass);
    } catch (T e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
      } 
}
```

Then the compiler says: Cannot use the type parameter T in a catch block

So how to solve this issue?

Comment: Replace T by Throwable since your type parameter may not be declared within your junit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By

```
Constructor<T> constructor = exceptionClass.getConstructor(String.class);
T result = constructor.newInstance(message);
```

You are creating result object of class passed as argument. Here by using 'T', only it means that you are constructing the result with the class which extends `Throwable`.

In the test method, even if do like this declare it:

```
    @Test
    public <T extends Throwable> void testCheckNotNull() {
        try {
        ValidationUtility.checkNotNull(null, "valuename", exceptionClass);
        } catch (T e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
          } 
    }
```

Still `T` is a type, not a class e.g. `Exception` which can be caught. As you have found in the error, you will not be able to catch a `Type`.

Since you know, Type `T` is representing classes extending `Throwable`, use may want to use `Throwable` in the catch block.

```
        } catch (Throwable e) {
```

Comment: I have another problem. How to create a exceptionClass in test case when invoking ValidationUtility.checkNotNull(null, "valuename", exceptionClass), since the exceptionClass type is Class<T>.                                                              Is just "Class<T> exceptionClass;" OK?

Comment: Jut by declaring `Class<T> exceptionClass`, exceptionClass can't be passed as argument to `checkNotNull` method as it is not initialized. If you are doing something else to initialize it, please share how is it initialized?

Comment: I just don't know how to initialize it, for its type is java.lang.Class<T>.

Comment: This is what I guessed earlier. Your exception class has to be some class which is extended from `Thwowable` e.g. `java.lang.NullPointerException`. In that case, you can call your `checkNotNull` as `ValidationUtility.checkNotNull(null, "valuename", java.lang.NullPointerException.class);`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I have known how to do.

Comment: Did you do something different? If yes, please share to help me and others.

Answer (score 2):

Since T is not known at compile time, you can't use it in a catch block like that. It is simply not something that is supported by the compiler, hence the error.

If your intent is to verify that the correct exception is thrown, I would suggest modifying your Test code like this:

```
@Test
public void testCheckNotNull() {
    try {
        ValidationUtility.checkNotNull(null, "valuename", exceptionClass);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        assertEquals(exceptionClass, e.getClass());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified in earlier answer you cannot catch T. This is because of erasure. I would suggest using the JUnit4 expected if you are expecting an exception.

```
@Test(expected = Throwable.class)
public void testCheckNotNull() throws Throwable {
     ValidationUtility.checkNotNull(null, "valuename", exceptionClass);
}
```

There is a bug with your test code too. If no exception is thrown then the test will still pass. You need to have a fail in there too

```
@Test
public void testCheckNotNull() {
    try {
      ValidationUtility.checkNotNull(null, "valuename", exceptionClass);
      fail("expected to throw")
    } catch (Throwable e) {}
}
```